# Ironpython and Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, ironpython

I'm trying my hands on ironpython instead of working on python and thought about writing simple program to fetch data from sqlite database. I've scrolled some of old questions and google (it's not showing decent resutls these days). One more question how to create redistributable for ironpython program if you're using notepad++ to code the programs ? (I know there is visual studio addon for ironpython but looking for alternatives).

**Do you suggest any good place to check for the (iron)python and sqlite tutorial ?**

Comment: Please don't use Notepad. If you're looking for a good Windows programming editor, use Notepad++.

Comment: @Rafe, Sorry forgot to type ++ after that. I use notepad++ and ultraedit (at home).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be here [THE WEBSITE, TECHNICAL BLOG AND PROJECTS OF MICHAEL FOORD](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/)

Comment: There isn't much documentation on sqlite database that i'm looking for.

Comment: @Mahesh If you follow the links in Michael Foord's blog you will see somme examples of code for use of ironPython and SQlite like here : http://hex-dump.blogspot.com/2006/09/ironpython-and-adonet-part-1.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. I was searching for SQLite resources specific to sharpdevelop so not sure if this will come handy. I'm pretty much beginner into sharpdevelop IDE.